# Using XIB/NIB files contained within downloaded bundles on iOS

Tags: ios, interface-builder, nsbundle

On the face of it, this seems a very simple problem but for some reason I can't quite get it to work.

I have a magazine-style app that downloads the data for each issue in the form of a zipped bundle.

Once downloaded, and unpacked, the app successfully accesses the various files contained within the bundle as expected. These include JSON, PNG, JPG, video and so on.

However, I also included a XIB file that contains the physical layout of the content in a series of UIViews and it is this file that I cannot use.

The file is present but when I try and load it using:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"ViewController" bundle: assetBundle];
```

I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/C6718DB8-0C0F-4D38-84E6-55C145279957/Documents/asset-4.bundle> (not yet loaded)' with name 'ViewController''
```

Now, is this an iOS imposed limitation on not accessing XIBs from downloaded bundles, or some mistake I'm making in calling up the XIB for use?

I cannot find any explicit prohibition on using fetched bundles in this way however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am unsure if you can 'legally' get away with this. But the problem is likely you are suppling a 'xib' instead of the compiled version the 'nib'.

You can do this manually from the command line by using the provided `ibtool` program.

`ibtool --errors --warnings --output-format human-readable-text --compile ${OUTPUT_NAME} ${INPUT_NAME}`

You'd then place the compiled .nib file into the bundle and load as you've been trying.

Comment: I guess it's legal because XIB is not executable code, but just interface layout.

Comment: Here's hoping it is! I've submitted a request to Apple anyway to find out - will post detail on their response when I have it.

Comment: It is likely fine, as you aren't loading any executable code. But there is always the chance.

Comment: I was compiling at the derived data location instead of the folder where the bundle was created. Thanks.

Comment: Any clues what that means? Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[40004:13603] CFPreferences: user home directory at file://localhost/Users/<USER>/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/User/ is unavailable. User domains will be volatile.